# Google Universal Analytics - force new session count same goal multiple times

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I believe I am not the only one having this issue and I was wondering if anyone has a way around it.

As Google states one goal can be only counted once per session. 
Unfortunately this is not good enough for me.
Let's say I have download button set as goal. Someone clicks on download button once, then after minute (within the same session) clicks on that button again. Google will count this as 1 goal completion when actually there was 2.
I have used session control parameter that forces new session to start within that hit (sc=start) and that kind of works. The only problem is that sometimes starting new session fails and then I am not getting correct count.

I will very appreciate if someone knows a way around it.

I am sending goals to Google analytics by protocol measurement parameter.
The URL I am sending looks like below

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345-6&cid=0d642efa134370ee444a952b777da6ec&t=pageview&sc=start&cm=cpc&cs=google&sr=-&sd=-&ul=-&je=0&fl=-&dt=%2Fphonecall.html&dh=&dr=&dp=%2Fphonecalls.html&z=44733587212
```

Is there a parameter that I am missing ?

Please help :)

Comment: If you want to count each time the button is clicked, within the same session, why not also track it as an event so you can see the total clicks in the event reports?

Comment: I need to be able to track this as goals. I am also using event tracking and that works.

Comment: @zachu It would be great to know why you need this to be a goal - this sounds like an excellent use case for a custom metric, so it would be interesting to know what a goal does for you that a custom metric or an event doesn't. Screwing up your session count to get multiple goal conversions does not sound like a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: mark all links on www site by UTM marks with same source (for example main_www_site), and than create a report in blog property by traffic source "main_www_site" and add here second dimension - pages.

Here is example of report:

[image]